# Unable to Explode HTTP Request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an input in which I intend to write image tags in the following way:

```
Tag1, Tag2, Tag3
```

Then create an array which I can loop through by using the explode() PHP function like this:

```
$tagsRaw = $request['artwork-tags'];
$tags = explode(',', $tagsRaw);

foreach($tags as $tag) {
    $tag = new Tag();
    $tag->name = $tag;
    $tag->save();

    $image->tags()->attach($tag);
}
```

Sadly I'm getting this error:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array,
>   string given, called in
>   C:\MAMP\htdocs\Art\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Grammars\Grammar.php
>   on line 681 ◀

I assume that I'm trying to explode() something which can't be exploded and that I'm not passing a string to explode().

Comment: Have you tried using `$tagsRaw  = $request->input('artwork-tags');` ?

Comment: and if you `dd($request['artwork-tags'])` what do you get?

Comment: I tried $tagsRaw = $request->input('artwork-tags'); and the result is the same. dd($request['artwork-tags']) gives me "tag1,tag2,tag3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding the `$tag` variable instantly.

```
$tagsRaw = $request['artwork-tags'];
$tags = explode(',', $tagsRaw);

foreach($tags as $tagName) {
    $tag = new Tag();
    $tag->name = $tagName;
    $tag->save();

    $image->tags()->attach($tag);
}
```

Comment: Oh my, it seems like this was the problem and not the explode. Thanks.

Comment: We've all been there don't beat yourself up about it. way too easy to reaad-over when you expect a more complex problem